# sitemap generation with multiple languages?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I'm setting up a multi-language page and I want to use the new TYPO3 v9 on-board sitemap generation feature. I read the [TYPO3 docs](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.4/Feature-84525-XMLSitemap.html#feature-84525-xml-sitemap) and set up a sitemap generation config for pages.

Now I can request `https://example.com/sitemap.xml` - this gives me a sitemap-index file with one entry that is pointing to a valid sitemap.xml file, but I cannot see any of the other languages.

It is possible to request `https://example.com/EN/sitemap.xml` also and I could add more `Sitemap:` directives to robots.txt, but is that correct?

Can somebody give me a hint how to configure TYPO3 sitemap feature **for multiple languages** within my typoscript setup?

Best regards, Lex

BTW: I'm using `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com/en/">` in HTML head area, also.

Answer (score 4):

If your language setup is correct, the sitemap will be generated for each language automatically.

In your site config (yaml) --> config/sites/your_site/config.yaml

Language configuration (example)

```
languages:
-
  title: English
  enabled: true
  languageId: '0'
  base: /
  typo3Language: en
  locale: en
  ....
-
  title: 
  enabled: true
  languageId: '1'
  base: /sv/
  typo3Language: sv
  locale: sv_SE
  ....
```

Would result in two languages on the same domain, with a path per language

- your-domain.xy/ = English
- your-domain.xy/sv/ = Swedish

If you want to use domains instead of a path (e.g. domain-1.xy for language 1 and domain-2.xy for language 2), you have to set the base url in your yaml config for each language.

For rewriting the sitemap:

```
routeEnhancers:
  PageTypeSuffix:
    type: PageType
    limitToPages:
      - 1
    map:
      sitemap.xml: 1533906435
```

This would result that the sitemap(s) are accessible with a rewritten url, limited to page with ID 1.

- your-domain.xy/sitemap.xml --> English sitemap, listing english pages
- your-domain.xy/sv/sitemap.xml --> Swedish sitemap, listing swedish pages

So to generate a sitemap per language, you need to:

- Setup your languages correctly (prefer the new yaml configuration instead of TypoScript)
- Activate the new TYPO3 SEO sysext
- Optional: rewrite type=1533906435 to sitemap.xml (or another name)

Comment: Short note for those who are also confused about a routeEnhancer or a static route. An xmlSitemap should never be a static route, even if it seems plausible. When using a static route, the automatic multilanguage feature does not work. It took me 2.5h to find my mistake. The solution from Mikel works perfect. Thank you

Comment: the question is how to have them both in one sitemap ...

Comment: It does not work for me. In the https://www.xxx.dm/sitemap.xml I do only have the sitemap of the default language. What do I do wrong?

routeEnhancers:
  PageTypeSuffix:
    type: PageType
    map:
      /: 0
      sitemap.xml: 1533906435

Thank for your help: